# Edit URL, keep domain part, strip others

Tags: regex, linux, bash, url

I've got a File full of URLs. Each line has one URL. I just want to keep the protocol and domain part.

Example:

```
https://example0.com/example.php?id=example0
https://example1.com/example.php?id=example1
https://example2.com/example.php?id=example2
```

Should be formatted to:

```
https://example0.com/
https://example1.com/
https://example2.com/
```

I'm using Linux Terminal, so Bash would be the best i think. I already heard of `sed` but i don't know how to use it or how to use expressions.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's|([^/]*//[^/]*/).*|\1|' file
```

Output:

```
    https://example0.com/
    https://example1.com/
    https://example2.com/
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
https?:\/\/[^\/]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/8MdA6I/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut` like this:

```
cut -d/ -f1-3 yourfile
```

It uses `/` as delimiter and selects the fields 1 to 3 (`//` beeing the empty field 2).

And if you really need the trailing slash, you could pipe everything to sed to add a `/` by adding this to the command:

```
| sed "s+$+/+g" `
```